# Send email add the attachement and all the records

Tags: apex

## Error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>
> Error is in expression '{!sendEmailFunction}' in page sendemailcontroller:
>
> Class.SendemailController.sendEmailFunction: line 10, column 1
>
> Class.SendemailController.sendEmailFunction: line 10, column 1

## Apex

```
public class SendemailController {
    public String caseId {get;set;}
        public list<case> getEmail{get;set;}
    Public SendemailController(){
    caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    system.debug('case id->'+caseId );
    }
    
    Public void sendEmailFunction(){
     getEmail = [SELECT Id, Contact.Email FROM Case WHERE id=:caseId];
    if(Contact.Email != null) {
    //string toaddress = Contact.Email;
    try {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    //string[] toAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
    String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'sfdcsrini@gmail.com'};
    //mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
    //mail.setReplyTo(toaddress);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Name');
    mail.setSubject('Testing email through apex');
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(true);
    mail.setPlainTextBody('This is test email body. This mail is being sent from apex code');
    //mail.setHtmlBody('<b> This is HTML body </b>' );
    
    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
    for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :caseId]){
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa.setFileName(a.Name);
    efa.setBody(a.Body);
    fileAttachments.add(efa);
    //mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
    }
    mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
    
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    
    }
    
    }
    
}
```

## Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page controller="SendemailController">
<apex:form >
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
sendEmail();
}
if(window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener('load',init,true)
else
window.attachEvent('onload',init)
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="sendEmail" action="{!sendEmailFunction}">
</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct a few things here:-

The error "**List has no rows for assignment to SObject**" occurs when the query doesn't return any rows. While a SELECT normally returns an array/list, these statements are using the shorthand syntax that assumes only one row is returned.
What’s not obvious is that it also assumes that exactly one row is returned!

While this is unlikely to occur for Contact, it is highly likely to occur for any custom objects you create, especially when a WHERE statement is used that might return zero rows, such as:

```
Player__c player = [SELECT Id from Player__c where Name = :username];
if (player != null)
 p = player.Id;
```

The above code will fail if there is no Player__c record with the matching username. It doesn't actually return a null.

It would be safer to do the following:

```
Player__c[] players = [SELECT Id from Player__c where Name = :username];
if (players.size() > 0)
p = players[0].Id;
```

What you are doing:-

```
getEmail = [SELECT Id, ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE id=:caseId];
    if(ContactEmail != null) {
```

You are directly accessing the ContactEmail field of Case record which you have queried. You can check the length of the array returned and then access the field like this:-

```
getEmail = [SELECT Id, ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE id=:caseId];
     if (getEmail.size() > 0){
        if(getEmail[0].ContactEmail != null) {
        }
     }
```

Comment: Public Pagereference sendEmailFunction(){
 getEmail = [SELECT Id,Contact.Email FROM Case WHERE id=:caseId]; 
 if (getEmail.size() > 0){
if(getEmail[0].Contact.Email != null) {  }}   . Child to parent relationship on if condition Contact.Email will not take it how to resolve this problem. showing error                 Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Contact at line 14 column 29 . 
 sanket kumar

Comment: @bingi it was due to wrong api name of Contact email field. I have corrected it. Instead of using Contact.Email use ContactEmail. I have updated the code in answer.